# How to add Case Owner to Case Team with Process builder and Flow?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I am looking some help and steps How to add Case Owner to Case Team with Process builder and Flow? I have created a flow with steps:

- Create a flow (auto-launched) and add three text variables:
- varCaseID (input)
- varPriorOwnerID (input)
- varCaseTeamMember

Started flow with get records , get Case Team Member records where User = varPriorOwnerID and Case = varCaseID.

Further I am bit confuse how to actually fetch Owner user Id also the Queues needs to be bypass
Can anyone please help on this would be very much helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- You can start with an autolaunched flow because debugging record-triggered is harder. But I would eventually use record-triggered after-save flow. You can use the save as a new flow feature and make the necessary changes.
- Run your flow whenever a case is created or updated and the Owner is changed. You can use priorvalue to check whether the owner has changed. Look for inspiration here (video): https://youtu.be/DKxLTRRXVe8
- $Record.owner should give you the owner. Look in the picker for the exact field.
- Check the case team and add the owner when necessary (I cannot detail this without building myself).